# A circular arc of length 17 feet subtends a central angle of 40 degrees. Find the radius of the circle in feet.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A circular arc of length 17 feet subtends a central angle of 40 degrees. Find the radius of the circle in feet.

What I have done is:

$$40/1 * \pi/180 = 2\pi/9$$

$$17 = r * 2\pi/9 $$

$$17 * 9/2\pi = 153/2\pi{\rm~ft}$$

I got $240.33183799961918$ feet

Answer is $24.35070629306$. where did I make mistake? Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to put parentheses around $2\pi$ when you did the division.

Comment: How can $\dfrac{153}{2\pi}$ be greater than $153$ ?

Answer (score 0):

community wiki answer so the question can be closed

Your answer of $\frac{153}{2\pi}~\text{ft}$ is correct.  However, when you entered it into your calculator, you failed to put parentheses around the $2\pi$ when you did the division, so you obtained
$$\frac{153}{2} \cdot \pi \approx 240.331838$$
rather than
$$\frac{153}{2\pi} \approx 24.3507062931$$